# Unable to get param in express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my code snippet. When I make an HTTP request to `http://localhost:3000/address` it works, but when I make a request to `http://localhost:3000/address/3` it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

```js
router.get('/:route(address(es)?|documents?)/:id?', async (req, res) => {
    const {route, id} = req.params;
    console.log(route, id)
});
```

Comment: Why is there a `?` at the end of `:/id`

Comment: Because I want to make it optional.

Comment: How does it go wrong? Is it 404'ing?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting a NOT Found error!

Answer (score 1):

Change the brackets in `address(es)` to square ones in order to avoid the 404 error, so that the route looks like this: `'/:route(address[es]?|documents?)/:id?'`